# The probability of a grouping occurring in a 2d array

Tags: probability, combinatorics, multidimensional-array

I have a 10x10 square 2d array of 5 colors that are randomly chosen. Basically a 10x10 pixel bitmap. I'm trying to figure out the probability of lets say 6 of the same color being in a 4 way grouping. By 4 way grouping I mean it neighbors are like colored pixels that are directly up, down, left, or right of the current pixel. I know that on average, 20 pixels of each color should exist on the image but I'm lost at trying to figure out a formula to find the probability of a group of like colored pixels.

I remember doing such calculations in a combinatorics class once, and would really appreciate any pointers on where I could relearn some of this.

Answer (score 0):

This [Reference](http://blog.iseesystems.com/tag/2d-array/) may useful to you.